# msys git compilation error

Tags: git, windows-7-x64, msys

I was trying to compile git under msys. But the compilation throws error saying it is unable to find zlib.h. The problem is the zlib.h is actually there in the `msys\include` directory.
Searching for the error, every one says it is the lack of zlib library. But since the msys\include directory already contains `zlib.h`, I was wondering what could be the problem!!

`Making
GIT_VERSION = 1.7.11
    * new build flags or prefix
    CC credential-store.o
In file included from credential-store.c:1:0:
cache.h:19:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
failure at line 262`

Answer (score 0):

It's a dependency for unobtrusive compression library archive (zlib), try installing zlib will solve this issue.

```
sudo wget zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
```

unzip, compile and install it, works good for me.